# Remove "Invalid Edit" rejection reason from tag wiki edit review dialog

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I'm referring to the *Invalid Edit* choice in wiki edits' rejection modal. While this is appropriate for the questions/answers edit suggestions, it can not be applied to wikis as there aren't normally existing posts there.

This is especially redundant with the availability of **Wiki not helpful** radio button present there, which brings me to another request.

Shouldn't the *wiki not helpful* choice be first or second in the list?

[image: here goes the pic, mkay?]

Comment: Also "radical edit" IMO. Who cares if the edit changes the entire original post as long as the edit is better/ more accurate than the original? Tag Wiki's aren't owned by the original author.

Comment: The one reason you specified that an Invalid Edit doesn't apply to a wiki is incorrect - wiki entries can indeed have invalid edits.